# About repunit and Mersenne numbers

Tags: mersenne-numbers, repunit-numbers

Let $r_n=11..11$ be the repunit of 1 repeated n times. In base 10, we have $r_n= (11..11)_{10}=\frac 19 (10^n-1)$ with a repetition of 1 n times. I would like to prove that if n is composite, then $r_n$ is also composite. I know that this question is addressed on this site, but I want to know if the following reasoning is correct. In base 2, $(11..11)_2= 2^n -1$. However, $M_n=2^n-1$ is a Mersenne number, and it is known that among the properties of Mersenne numbers, if n is composite, then $M_n$ is composite. Therefore, if n is composite, we conclude that $(11..11)_2$ is composite.
**Question** Is it sufficient  to say that $r_n=(11..11)_{10}$ is also composite?

Comment: No, because you are looking at two different numbers. However the same proof that works in base 2 works with suitable adaptations also in base 10.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you mean by two different numbers.

Comment: I mean how could just knowing $M_n$ is composite imply that $r_n$ is composite?

Comment: The fact that a number is composite when read in one base doesn't mean it is composite in another.  Why should it?   $10_2$ is prime, for instance.

Comment: Thank's i understand